# Changing POST data prior to saving a model in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Disclaimer**: I'm a DRF/class-based-views newb.

I have a situation where the client to my API can't know the ID of a resource, but it does know a unique identifier of that resource (its name).

This is a problem when the client sends a separate resource that has a Foreign Key to the first via POST. For example... the client sends the following data (Signal being the FK):

```
{"signal_name": "signal1", "value": 5}
```

But the Model expects:

```
{"signal": 1, "value": 5}
```

When `self.CONTENT` gets to my custom post method, it's already been validated and is empty. 
 So, where/how can I swap that data out prior to the data getting validated/rejected?
Do I need a custom validation method?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You could write a Middleware class that intercepts avery request/response and modifies that specific value, or erases it.

Comment: I know this isn't much help for the question at hand, but I'd *strongly* recommend you look into updating to version 2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried messing with the fields and extra-fields attributes on the resource, but couldn't get it to not validate it as wrong.  So I ended up just adding the field in the 'signal_name' field into the model and matching it up to the signal's id in the post method.  (Thankfully, in this case we had a non-enforced FK to Signal, so I could do wait to give a value to signal)
 I'll check back for a few days to see if anyone actually knows how to do this better.  Also, thanks for the suggestions Pizza and Tom!